# The method setDelimiter(String) in the type DelimitedLineTokenizer is not applicable for the arguments (char) - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to **migrate Spring Batch Core v 2.1.8.RELEASE to 4.0.3** (Using maven project not Spring Boot), I see my code is breaking and I really need make the things consistent with this latest version as well

Error:

> The method setDelimiter(String) in the type DelimitedLineTokenizer is not applicable for the arguments (char)

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char

Code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineCallbackHandler;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;

public class HeaderCallbackTokenizer extends InterningDelimitedLineTokenizer implements LineCallbackHandler {
    private char delimiter = DELIMITER_COMMA;
    
    @Override
    public void setDelimiter(char delimiter) {
        super.setDelimiter(delimiter);
        
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void handleLine(String line) {
        if (line.startsWith("X" + delimiter)) {
            List<String> names = doTokenize(line);
            
            names.set(0,  "TYPE");
            
            setNames(names.toArray(new String[0]));
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public FieldSet tokenize(String line) {
        return super.tokenize(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a string instead of a char then?

Comment: @sp00m - hey, its not easy to fix, just to make String, things are happening internally and I see batch core has drastically changed from that version!

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/61. You need to update your code to pass a `String` instead of `char`. This is part of your migration work.

And BTW, I would **not** skip a major version (v3 in your case) in any migration path in order to minimize the gap between versions in each step of the migration.